# How should protocol/implementation pairs be adjusted for the Swift API design guidelines?

Tags: swift, naming-conventions, api-design

In the new [Swift API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), the commonly-used `Type` suffix for protocols is being dropped. While this is easy to do for protocols that are stand-alone (`SequenceType` becomes `Sequence`), I'm not sure how to update my APIs in which a protocol provides the base for an implementation. Here's some examples from popular frameworks:

- The [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/result) µframework provides `Result`, a concrete success/fail enumeration, and `ResultType`, a generic base protocol for a success/fail type, to which `Result` conforms.
- [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/reactivecocoa/reactivecocoa)'s main types are `Signal` and `SignalProducer`, which are backed by `SignalType` and `SignalProducerType`.

In both cases, much of the implementation is in extensions of the protocols, allowing extensions to use the full power of type constraints, and allowing the implementations to be generic. This is different from the case of protocols with `AnySequence`-style type-erasing types: you aren't *really* expected to implement these protocols on your own, or unify disparate types.

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question because I'd like a (definitive) answer.

Answer (score 21):

I would advise using the suffix `Protocol`. This is consistent with how the standard library have stripped the `Type` suffix from protocols, as stated in [SE-0006](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md):

> On high level, the changes can be summarized as follows.
>
> - Strip `Type` suffix from protocol names. In a few special cases this
>     means adding a `Protocol` suffix to get out of the way of type names
>     that are primary (though most of these we expect to be obsoleted by
>     Swift 3 language features).

For example, `GeneratorType` was renamed to `IteratorProtocol`.

And, for example, is also how both [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) & [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) have updated their APIs for Swift 3. `ResultType` was renamed to `ResultProtocol` (in [this commit](https://github.com/antitypical/Result/pull/167/commits/e30d059689e21536eb807ce9f977db7aea2fe75f)), and `SignalType` was renamed to `SignalProtocol`, and `SignalProducerType` was renamed to `SignalProducerProtocol` (in [this commit](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/commit/521a73144053ad8a3d6013008ef96398733ba604)).

Although it's worth noting that in a vast majority of these cases, such protocols only exist as a workaround for the lack of [parameterised extensions](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#parameterized-extensions).

For example, we cannot currently say:

```
struct SomeGenericThing<T> {
    var value: T
}

extension <T> Array where Element == SomeGenericThing<T>, T : Comparable {

}
```

But introducing a protocol allows us to realise the generic placeholder(s) as associated type(s), which we can then use in constraints:

```
protocol SomeGenericThingProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    var value: T { get set }
}

struct SomeGenericThing<T> : SomeGenericThingProtocol {
    var value: T
}

extension Array where Element : SomeGenericThingProtocol, Element.T : Comparable {
    // ...
}
```

Therefore once parameterised extensions are supported, we'll be able to do away with such protocols.